# ssh login issues at github and authentcation issues while doing a git push

Tags: git, ssh, github

I have been getting the following issue when I do a ssh git@github.com

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
```

After this usually we receive a confirmation message saying you are authenticated which I did not receive

I have tried restarting issues
Now I have replaced my ssh key ( which is not a solution ) and tried it again but did not help

Also everytime I do a

```
git push origin master
```

At github:
It prompts for

```
Username: 
Password:
```

At gitorious the same

```
git push origin master
```

I get the answer as

> ```
> fatal: protocol error: expected sha/ref, got '
> ```
>
> ---------------------------------------------- The git:// protocol is read-only.
>
> Please use the push url as listed on
>   the repository page.
>   ----------------------------------------------'

This part is solved

> Again when I do an
>
> ```
> ~/.ssh> ssh-add id_rsa
> ```
>
> I get this --
>
> ```
>  Could not open a connection to your authentication agent
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The git:// protocol is read-only.

This should explain so many issues. You used the read only URL instead of read-write one.

Example. I cloned the github repo of apt-offline and then then do a

> $ git remote show origin

It shows

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@github.com:manish/apt-offline2.git
  Push  URL: git@github.com:manish/apt-offline2.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

Have a look at `git@github.com:manish/apt-offline2.git`
This is my read-write git URL

If I clone it with my read-only URL with

> git clone git://github.com/manish/apt-offline2.git

Then that would change to `git://github.com/manish/apt-offline2.git` and any attempts at push would give an error

So you need to provide the output of command

> $ git remote show origin

provided your default remote is origin. To check all remotes you can use the command

> $ git remote

---

**CAUTION**

Don't ever edit .git directory. If the remote `remotename` is wrong then

to remove a remote use

> $ git remote rm remotename

and then to add

> $ git remote add remotename URL

Comment: The solution would be to edit the .git/config file and change the repos to read-write url at orign

Answer (score 4):

Try again after starting `ssh-agent`. (Should solve 2. Problem)

Comment: The second one was solved sorry.. Any idea about the first one.. It seems that github  is unable to login / use my ssh keys